# Json Code is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, post

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://chkdin.com/dev/api/peoplearoundmexy/?";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

NSString *parameterString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"skey=%@&user_id=%@",@"XXXXXXX",@"3225"];


NSLog(@"%@",parameterString);


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setURL:url];

[request setValue:parameterString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSData *postData = [parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]);
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

This is my json parsing, my problem is when I am hit this api it is showing

```
{
  message = "Valid skey required.";
status = 0;
}
```

But this api is working in safari.i am think is the problem is for request adding to url wrong. can you help me please....

Comment: what the problem u faced

Comment: result show is valid key required, but the skey is working in url.

Comment: http://chkdin.com/dev/api/peoplearoundmexy/?skey=sa6rw9er7twefc9a7dvcxcheckedin&user_id=3225

Comment: please find the above url link.

Comment: ur request type is get or post

Comment: The userId has permission to access data?.

Comment: my request is post method.

Comment: There are certain type of secret keys, or we can say the secret keys are for specific platform. some secret keys are only allowed to access in web others are for mobile. check if there is some limitation like this

Comment: ya permission is there.

Comment: are you sure that the method is post, I am seeing the method as GET, when  I tried the link you shared

Comment: ya sure that is post method.

Comment: your "skey" key is not valid.

Comment: No key is working.

Comment: `postData ` seems wrong to me. It should be `NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"skey":@"sa6rw9er7twefc9a7dvcxcheckedin",@"user_id":@"3225"} options:0 error:nil];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got response through AFNetworking 3

try this

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:@"http://chkdin.com/dev/api/peoplearoundmexy/?" parameters:@{@"skey":@"sa6rw9er7twefc9a7dvcxcheckedin",@"user_id":@"3225"} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    }];
```

[image]

Comment: download afnetworking library through this url  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: yes it is working thank you, I am using afnetworking.

Answer (score 1):

i tried following code without `AFNetworking` and its working fine.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skey=%@&user_id=%@",@"sa6rw9er7twefc9a7dvcxcheckedin",@"3225"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://chkdin.com/dev/api/peoplearoundmexy/?%@",post]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:nil];
NSError *error;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]);
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```